# Approvals : how to Withdraw an email automatically Approved before the activation of the Approval process

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, approval-process, approve-action

We created an Approval process.
So all the emails already created on Content Builder before the activation of the Approval process are Approved by default.

However, how can we do to EDIT an email already approved (so created before the activation of the Approval process) ?
We can't see the WITHDRAW button on these emails approved by default created before the activation of the Approval process. We can only see it on emails created and approved once the Approval process is activated.

Answer (score 2):

Open the email and click on the arrow next to 'Approved' and choose 'Withdraw'. Once the email is withdrawn the Edit functionality becomes available. In oorder to use this content to Send, you will need to go through the Approval process again.

NOTE: Withdrawing email content WILL NOT cancel scheduled sends. Once an email is queued for sending the user will need to Cancel the scheduled send itself